Changing of water in the Rotary Evaporator RC 600 affecting its performance

The KNF Rotary Evaporator RC 600 as shown above has not had its water(from the bath) changed for quite some time now(my best estimate is roughly 2 months). There is also a dead fly in it. Yet it is used every other week. I asked a senior in the lab for permission to change the water in the bath, but he told me that there is absolutely no need to do so. It would simply be a waste of time and effort.
Hence, I wanted to know whether leaving water in the bath for long periods of time has any effect on the performance of the instrument?Also would the development of rust(as shown in the image) and/or corrosion affect the water bath in anyway?
Lastly, there are a few pigment stains on the device as well, near the buttons and on the outer side. Any ideas to clean those up?

Independent of esthetics and chemistry, help the creature to get out of the bath.
On occasion i) a round bottom flask accidentally slides out of your hand and drops into the bath.  Or ii) a clip fails to keep it attached, e.g. to the optional splash guard (for smaller flasks, it simultaneously can be a helpful "extension" to reach the bath) and either bath liquid enters the evaporating flask, or/and product spills into the bath and you want/must recover your product by extract from the bath.  Based on personal experience, such a rescue is easier if the bath is kept clean of floating/dissolved/decomposing residues to then requiring "only" a couple of extractions of the cooled bath (and only little additional purification [wash/back extraction/drying, recrystallization; distillation]) than an additional chromatography on top.
If there are many samples in small round bottom flasks to concentrate (say of a volume $\pu{25 mL}$, or less), you may mount them to the evaporator with the splash guard and an additional adapter (for the narrow neck). You may fill the bath to the upper mark which usually is fine/acceptable until you mount a flask with larger displacement without an adapter ($250, 500, \pu{1000 mL}$). By immersion of these, your bath now can overflow.  The rotation of the flask equally lifts and sprays some of water, too.  Now you/your colleagues have to mop up the bench/floor again and again instead of doing something more useful (update the log, mount/dismount a column, etc) in parallel to the ongoing concentration.  It is not so much about the performance of the bath running during the day typically around $\pu{50 ^\circ{}C}$ (if it is water* based); because if you need to rotavap large quantities, there are larger evaporators (e.g., R-220 ex with a $\pu{20 L}$ evaporating flask), too.
The stains the picture depicts equally could be by partially corroded (metal) Keck clips introduced over time e.g. if you mount a small 25 mL flask to the evaporator via splash guard and an additional adapter for a more narrow neck.

* Tap water often contains too many minerals (hard water) to be a useful bath liquid in the long run (think removing the deposits with vinegar like for an electric kettle).  Some groups hence use softened water.  Quoting the English manual of the R-100 by Buchi (the first company successful to commercialize rotary evaporators) advises e.g.

5.8 Setting up and filling the heating bath
Do not use pure distilled water or de-ionised water.
If pure distilled or de-ionised water has to be used, add 1 to 2 g of Borax ($\ce{Na2B4O7 x 10 H2O}$) per litre of water.
[...]
The recommended fluid for use in the heating bath is water. Normal tap water may be mixed with distilled water with a mixing ratio of up to 1:1 according to the water hardness.
(p. 25 of the manual, revision 09.2022)


(+1) Thanks for the input. I plan on cleaning up this weekend and I got the poor fly out.
